# Getting IEnumerable<IDictionary> from WCF RIA DomainServiceClass into Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am currently using a WCF RIA domain service class to generate a list of dictionary objects.

```
    [Invoke]
    public IEnumerable<IDictionary> GenerateData()
    {
        List<IDictionary> newList = new List<IDictionary>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict["ID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            dict["Name"] = "Name_" + i;
            dict["Index"] = i;
            newList.Add(dict);
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

I want to pass this list to Silverlight:

```
DomainContext _myContext = new DomainContext();
InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<IDictionary>> loadop4 = this._myContext.GenerateData();
loadop4.Completed += new System.EventHandler(loadop4_callback);

void loadop4_callback(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<IDictionary>> iop = sender as InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<IDictionary>>;
    //... do stuff with IOP  
}
```

But it's giving me this error in VS2010:

```
Error 1 Operation named 'GenerateData' does not conform to the required signature. Return types must be an entity or complex type, a collection of entities or complex types, or one of the predefined serializable types.
```

How do I fix this? I thought Lists of dictionaries was supported in Silverlight

Comment: Try to send a list or an array rather than an IEnumerable.

Comment: Same message. It doesn't like my GenerateData() function for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The only dictionary that ria services supports is Dictionary, so, no way to send an object so complex.
I'd rather serialize my dictionary (DataContractSerializer can do the trick quite easily) and return an IEnumerable of string to the client, where you can then desrialize it.

EDIT:
I've just written a [minipost](http://mcasamento.blogspot.it/2012/09/wcf-ria-services-overcoming-limitations.html) on my blog for this